# C# IF statement double result

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm new to `C#` learning, I followed a tutorial and then tried throwing an error message myself for every time my IF statement is false. here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;



namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string SecretWord = "Banana";
            string Guess = "";
            int GuessCount = 0;
            int GuessLimit = 4;
            bool OutOfGuesses = false;


            while (Guess != SecretWord && !OutOfGuesses)             
            {
                if (GuessCount < GuessLimit)
                {
                    Console.Write("Enter a Guess: ");
                    Guess = Console.ReadLine();
                    GuessCount++;

                } else

                {
                    OutOfGuesses = true;
                }

                if (Guess != SecretWord)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Guess");

                }



            }  

              if (OutOfGuesses)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You Lose");

            }   else {

                Console.WriteLine("You Win!");

            }               




            Console.ReadLine();

        }

    }
}
```

The output is this:

Enter a Guess: dsadasd

Wrong Guess

Enter a Guess: dsdasd

Wrong Guess

Enter a Guess: dasdas

Wrong Guess

Enter a Guess: dasdas

Wrong Guess

Wrong Guess

You Lose

I can't figure out why I am getting **double "Wrong Guess" at the end**. does anyone know why?

Comment: Try to use the debugger and step through the program. Hint: if you're out of guesses , your guess still not equals the secret word. So, move your last if statement (or find an alternative) ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The final time around...

1. `guess` still doesn't equal `secretword`
2. `OutOfGuesses` is not yet True
3. `GuessCount < GuessLimit` is True

So, you don't ask the question, you set OutOfGuesses to be True, but then as `guess` is not the same as `secretword` you print the message again.

To fix this, you need to set `OutOfGuesses` to true outside of the `if/else` block. Check if they've reached their limit, and set it to True, at the end of the loop.

i.e. something like...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string SecretWord = "Banana";
            string Guess = "";
            int GuessCount = 0;
            int GuessLimit = 4;
            bool OutOfGuesses = false;


            while (Guess != SecretWord && !OutOfGuesses)             
            {
                Console.Write("Enter a Guess: ");
                Guess = Console.ReadLine();
                GuessCount++;

                if (GuessCount >= GuessLimit)
                {
                    OutOfGuesses = true;
                }

                if (Guess != SecretWord)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Wrong Guess");

                }

            }  

            if (OutOfGuesses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Lose");

            } 
            else 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Win!");
            }                

            Console.ReadLine();

        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dasdas is not your secret word, so the if statement is true, if you insert Banana your if statement will be false